# "Failed to load ApplicationContext" using @ContextConfiguration("/applicationContext.xml") with Maven structure

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-test

I'm trying to run a JUnit Test using Spring but the console shows:
 ***Failed to load ApplicationContext*** error. I'm using the Maven structure, and I have the `applicationContext.xml` file in `src/main/resources` folder. I have read all the questions related and tried the solutions, but no success.

[Here is the folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXl0s.png).

Here is the code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/applicationContext.xml")
public class ConsultarProveedorPorLlave {

@Resource
private SessionFactory fabricaSesionPostgreSQL;

@Test
public void test()
{
    Session sesion = fabricaSesionPostgreSQL.openSession();
    Proveedor proveedor = (Proveedor) sesion.get(Proveedor.class, 1);
    assertNotNull("El proveedor no existe", proveedor);
    System.out.println("Proveedor: " + proveedor.getProveedor() + " - " + proveedor.getNombre() + " - " + proveedor.getEstado());
    sesion.close();
}
```

Here is the error trace:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'fabricaSesionPostgreSQL' defined in
>   class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to
>   convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type
>   [javax.sql.DataSource] for property 'dataSource'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   [java.lang.String] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource] for
>   property 'dataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy
>   found     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
>     ... 25 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to
>   convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type
>   [javax.sql.DataSource] for property 'dataSource'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   [java.lang.String] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource] for
>   property 'dataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy
>   found     at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:591)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:603)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1527)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
>     ... 39 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot
>   convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type
>   [javax.sql.DataSource] for property 'dataSource': no matching editors
>   or conversion strategy found  at
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:576)
>     ... 45 more

Here is the `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>sacc</groupId>
<artifactId>sacc</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
    <postgresql.version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</postgresql.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate -->

    <!-- PostgreSQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- PostgreSQL -->

    <!-- JUnit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JUnit -->

    <!-- Spring Framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Framework -->
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is the ***applicationContext.xml*** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd">

<bean id="fuenteDatosPostgreSQL"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sacc" />
    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="admin" />
</bean>
<bean id="fabricaSesionPostgreSQL"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate_postgresql.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="dataSource" value="fuenteDatosPostgreSQL" />
</bean>
<bean id="gestorTransaccionesPostgreSQL"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="fabricaSesionPostgreSQL" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="gestorTransaccionesPostgreSQL" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com" scoped-proxy="interfaces" />
```

Comment: Add your `applicationContext.xml` to question. Clearly the problem is your `DataSource` bean: `Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource]`

Comment: Give people your applicationContext.xml file

Comment: I added the applicationContext.xml file.

Comment: Yeah, and you got your answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: based on your provided `applicationContext.xml`

`<property name="dataSource" value="fuenteDatosPostgreSQL" />`

needs to be

`<property name="dataSource" ref="fuenteDatosPostgreSQL" />`.

That way it looks for the object referenced by "fuenteDatosPostgreSQL" rather than the simply the String "fuenteDatosPostgreSQL".

Comment: I'll look into it.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The exception clearly shows

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource] for property 'dataSource':`

When you `reference` bean you need to use `ref` instead you used `value`.

```
<bean id="fabricaSesionPostgreSQL"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate_postgresql.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="dataSource" value="fuenteDatosPostgreSQL" />
</bean>
```

replace the line with

```
<property name="dataSource" ref="fuenteDatosPostgreSQL" />
```

Comment: Thank you, that is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your configuration into src/main/resourcesr and try use try @ContextConfiguration("classpath:applicationContext.xml") in your unit test.